# Pyramid.security questions: Double cookies? Insecure cookies? Expiration?

Tags: python, cookies, security, pylons, pyramid

I'm taking my first foray into the Pyramid security module. I'm using this login code to set the auth_tkt:

```
@view_config(route_name='LoginForm', request_method='POST', renderer='string')
class LoginForm(SimpleObject):
    def __call__(self):

        emailAddress = self.request.params.get('emailAddress')
        password = self.request.params.get('password')

        if emailAddress != 'testemail@gmail.com' or password != 'testpassword':
            errorDictionary = { 'message' : "Either the email address or password is wrong." }
            self.request.response.status = 400
            return json.dumps( errorDictionary, default=json_util.default)

        testUserGUID = '123123123'

        headers = remember(self.request, testUserGUID)
        return HTTPOk(headers=headers)
```

It seems to work ok, but there are some puzzling details:

First of all, 2 cookies actually get set instead of one. The 2 cookies are identical (both with name "auth_tkt") except for one difference: one has a host value of  ".www.mydomain.com" while the other cookie has a host value of "www.mydomain.com" Why are 2 cookies being set instead of one? What's the significance of the difference host values?

Question 2, web tools reports that neither cookie is secure. What can I do to make sure the cookie/s are secure?

Question 3: Both cookies have an expiration value of "At end of session". What does this mean and how can I customize the expiration value myself? What's the recommended practice for login cookie expiration times?

Question 4: I don't understand why the first argument of "remember" is self.request instead of self.request.response. Shouldn't the data be remembered on the response object, not the request object?

Comment: Presumably you meant `serverUserGUID = '1123123123'`; you call `remember` with that variable name.

Comment: Thanks you...I fixed the error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Actually, 3 cookies are generated; one without a `Domain` key, one with, and a 3rd with the wildcard version of your domain (the leading dot). Your browser usually either merges the two or ignores one of those (which one differs by browser, which is why 2 are set).

   That last cookie is generated when the `wild_domain` option is set on the `AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy` (True by default); see the [`AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy` API](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/authentication.html). You need this if your authentication cookie is to be shared between different subdomains (think app1.domain, app2.domain); your browser won't share cookies across subdomains without a wildcard cookie.
2. You need to set the `secure` option on your auth policy for cookies to get the secure flag set. Again, see the [API](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/authentication.html).
3. No expiration is set, which means that the cookies are deleted when you close your browser (the end of the session your browser shows you). If you want your users to be logged out when they close the browser, leave this as the default.

   *Only* if you want sessions to last across browser closures, set a cookie maximum age, see the `max_age` option in the [API](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/authentication.html). This option will cause browsers to store the cookie on disk to persist between browser closures, and delete them when the maximum age has passed.

   Do note that the `AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy` policy object can manage login sessions in a more fine-grained manner by limiting how long it'll consider any authentication cookie valid, and will let you set up a cookie refresh policy. With such a refresh policy in place users will receive new (refreshed) cookies as they continuing to use your application, but if they don't connect to your server within a set period of time, their cookie would be considered invalid and they would have to log in again.

   See the `timeout` and `reissue_time` options in the [API documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/authentication.html) for more detail on how to configure this.
4. The policy object requires several pieces of information from the request to be able to generate the cookies, not least of all the host name of your server.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. One thing I want to know is, is the AuthTKTAuthentication Policy safe against csrf attacks?? If not how can we make it safe. And one other thing how can we use it for servers which connect to a client mobile app. The cookie thing would be difficult i guess. And wouldn't token options be better??

Comment: Set `http_only` to `True` to tell browsers to hide the cookie from JavaScript; this makes CSRF attacks that steal the cookie ineffective.  Cookies are just HTTP headers, your mobile client will have to manage them just as they would for any other site. No idea what you mean by token options.

Comment: I am not sure if that would prevent csrf attacks, the cookies are automatically attached to any request to the domain they were set from. Csrf attacks does exactly that. I am asking about creating tokens and serving to clients and the server remembers the token issued to particular user.

Comment: @SaranshMohapatra: CSRF attack vectors are the pages themselves, and a common aim is to steal the cookie, sending it on to another server. That is prevented with `http_only` set on. You can also set `include_ip` to True to bind the cookie to a specific IP address, so stealing the cookie is meaningless. The cookie *is* a token, one that uses secure hashing (with a server-side secret) to encode the username of the logged in user.

Comment: @SaranshMohapatra: This cookie has otherwise *nothing* to do with CSRF protection, for that you use [the session cookie](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.0-branch/narr/sessions.html#preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-attacks) to set a per-form token.