# Is there a security risk when changing the timeout of the session cookie?

Tags: python, security, session, pyramid

Suppose I have a pyramid application where I use `UnencryptedCookieSessionFactoryConfig` for csrf tokens and authentication with `SessionAuthenticationPolicy`. The default timeout for the session cookie is 1200, which means that my user is disconnect after 20 minutes, which is quite annoying.

I was tempted to raise the timeout or even remove it, and to set a max_age to make it survive the browser, but I guess the timeout is there for a good reason.

Is there a security risk with having an long-lived session cookie ? Is it considered bad practice ?

My guess is that the csrf token should be short-lived. In that case, I should use `AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy` for the authentication. Same question : is an authentication cookie with a max_age far in the future a bad practice ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the timeout only applies to users that do not contact the server in that time. A visit to your site within 20 minutes refreshes the cookie.

Yes, there is a security risk in allowing longer time-outs on cookies; it creates a longer window in which to compromise the client computer or try to exploit a XSS flaw in your application. I'd still set *a* limit on the cookie.

I'd use the `AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy` to manage user authentication sessions anyway; it offers more fine-grained control over session lifetime (see this [older answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232364/pyramid-security-questions-double-cookies-insecure-cookies-expiration/12234593#12234593)).

You could even write a small piece of  javascript that pokes the server periodically when the user is active (keyboard and mouse input, poking, say, once every minute) to refresh that cookie; close the browser, session gone automatically within 20 minutes.