# Pyramid AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy in plain English

Tags: cookies, pyramid

I'm thinking of using a token-based authentication policy for my Pyramid backend & Angular frontend app.

I read many articles today and it has come to my attention that a token based auth policy seems to be the way to go for AngularJS authentication where the token is passed to the client and [Angular saves the token using a Service](http://nils-blum-oeste.net/angularjs-send-auth-token-with-every--request/) of some sort.

Reading the source of the `AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy` I realized that it uses `AuthTktCookieHelper` to generate a *cookie*.  I'm a bit confused here:  Is a token the same as a cookie?  If so, then how would I be able to retrieve the value of the cookie and pass it on to the client after the user has successfully logged in?

Comment: A cookie is used to store a token. A token is a value that is opaque to the receiver; it is a 'thingumy' you pass back each time you want to talk to server and the server knows how to recognize it. All the receiver needs to know it is a token and that it is important.

Comment: I covered this code in some technical answers before, do [pyramid AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy secret parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12767843) and [Pyramid.security questions: Double cookies? Insecure cookies? Expiration?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12234593) help at all?

Comment: Once configured, the handling of the cookie is meant to be transparent to your application; read the [security chapter](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/narr/security.html) of the Pyramid documentation on how security works; and the [Adding Authorization section](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/tutorials/wiki2/authorization.html) of the tutorial to see how to handle logging in; the `remember()` call is all your application ever needs to have the token generated and the cookie set for you.

Comment: A HA! Your third comment saying that `remember()` call returns the token.  In the documentation and source code comments, all it says is that it returns some headers; that means nothing to me, sadly.  Ok....so when I make the `remember()` call, it returns me a token which I can pass to the client, is that correct?

Comment: `remember()`, sadly, returns headers. Those headers do things like set cookies. Add those headers to the response. Those headers contain the right information for the client; usually one or more `Set-Cookie` headers.

Comment: The whole token handling should be transparent to your application *too*. All you need to use is `remember()` and `forget()`; however the underlying implementation handles these details should not really trouble you.

Comment: The things is that I need authenticate my Angular application via a REST endpoint like `/auth/login`.  It only seems to accept JSON responses from the server, which means I won't be able to return a `pyramid.response.Response(headers=remember(request, username))`.  The client needs to somehow know that it has indeed successfully logged in.

Comment: Your JSON response is still a HTTP response. It still has headers.

Comment: Your view has *at least* a `request` object; `request.respones.headers` can be updated with the values returned from `remember()`.

Comment: Oh, ok wait, so you're saying that I can continue to return a `pyramid.response.Response(headers=remember(request, username))` and maybe tack on some json data to the body of the response and return it, and Angular will still be able to access the HTTP status codes in javascript via say:  `response.status`?

Comment: I am saying that if you use a JSON renderer on your view, you'd use `request.response.headerlist.extend(remember(request, username))`; the returned HTTP response then has the right headers. Wellbehaved HTTP clients will then return those cookies on future requests, letting Pyramid extract the token and authenticate the user again.

Comment: Then when the client makes a separate request later on, Pyramid will just do its thing and automatically check the cookie by itself?  This is what you mean by "token handling should be transparent"

Comment: You can *also* return a `Response()` object with a JSON body and the right headers; that's all a JSON renderer does for you really.

Comment: Yes, requests that come in with a cookie will let Pyramid automatically handle that cookie and authenticate the user.

Comment: That's all covered in the Security documentation I already linked you to.

Comment: ok, NOW I get it.  I have read your other articles that you mentioned above before I posted this question, but I just couldn't get this part.  Thanks for the enlightenment, I wish I could thank you in person.